# SharePoint anonymous access does not work on DispForm.aspx within list

Tags: rss, moss, anonymous-users

I have a MOSS site that uses anonymous access, which works everywhere I need it except on DispForm.aspx for a custom list.

Basically there is a custom list containing links to news articles on the internet. I have made the list available as an RSS feed, and you can pull up the feed itself just fine anonymously. However, the feed  contains links to the individual items in SharePoint, e.g. /Lists/My List/DispForm.aspx?ID=23.

Anonymous users have "view items" access to the list in question and NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users Read access to the list and to the individual items in question. I tried it with Full Control too.

I tried adding a location exception in the web.config, i.e.

```
    <location path="Lists/My%20List/DispForm.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

I checked the SharePoint log and I have this error:

```
PermissionMask check failed: asking for 0x00001000, have 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This office.microsoft.com [knowledge base article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101130181033.aspx#EnableListLibrary) explains what is need to enable anonymous acces on a list. Could you check if you have performed all actions mentioned under the *Enable anonymous access on a list or library* section?

P.S. I have vote to close this question by moving it to serverfault, where it belongs.

Comment: Yes, I've taken the steps described in that document. Anonymous access is enabled on the site for "Entire Web Site." Anonymous access is enabled in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It seems that pages under /Forms in lists and document libraries (such as DispForm.aspx) are locked down for anonymous users, apparently by default. This happens through a feature called ViewFormPagesLockdown. When this feature is enabled, anonymous users cannot hit those pages no matter what permissions you have on the lists themselves. When it is deactivated, you have to go in and assign anonymous permissions (in my case I'm pretty sure I already had anonymous access enabled on one list, but I had to change it to something else (Edit) then change it back for it to begin working).